# Difference between session.Close() and session.Dispose()

Tags: nhibernate

What is difference between `session.Close()` and `session.Dispose()`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From the Nhibernate Source code:

```
private void Dispose(bool isDisposing)
{
    using (new SessionIdLoggingContext(base.SessionId))
    {
        if (!base.IsAlreadyDisposed)
        {
            log.Debug(string.Format("[session-id={0}] executing real Dispose({1})", base.SessionId, isDisposing));
            if (!(!isDisposing || base.IsClosed))
            {
                this.Close();
            }
            base.IsAlreadyDisposed = true;
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
}
```

So Dispose method calls `Close()`. Calling either `Close()` or `Dispose()` methods will close the Session not allowing you to work with it anymore.

Answer (score 11):

Calling `session.Close()` will close the session but not dispose of the object.

Calling `session.Dispose()` (usually through the use of a using block) will close the session if it is open as well as perform the extra operations of `Dispose()`.

Answer (score 2):

This question is a few years old now but it still shows up in top results through search engines so I thought I'd still be worth adding a comment. Also, I'm using NHibernate 5.1.1 so maybe this is something that has changed since the questions was originally posted.

That out of the way, turns out that if you call `session.Close()` within a `TransactionScope`, you will get a `System.Transactions.TransactionAbortedException`. If you take a look at the `Close()` method remarks inside `SessionImpl` you will find this:

`/// 
        /// Do not call this method inside a transaction scope, use Dispose instead, since
        /// Close() is not aware of distributed transactions
        ///`

So at least within the context of a `TransactionScope`, `Close()` must be avoided.